# A common name for size and location?

Tags: c#, location, size, naming, naming-conventions

This might be a bit silly question since it's all about terms and naming, but I find it important for me to name my methods correctly.

I'm creating a windows form and I need a method that sets buttons' and textboxes' sizes and locations (at initializing process, and every time my form gets resized). What should this method be called?

At the moment I'm using name `SetSizeAndLocation();`, but I find it quite disturbing. Is there a common term for size and location?

Comment: What's wrong with having two separate methods?

Comment: What about something a bit more generic, like `setProperties()`?

Comment: I agree with @jimmy_keen you can have two methods or properties.

Comment: @jimmy_keen I never ever need to call them separately. If I must adjust the size, I will also have to adjust the location. And always calling two methods instead of one is not that good.

Comment: How about `SetBounds()` ?

Comment: @PatrikLippojoki as I understand you correctly  your concern is about readability not how if you call them separately.

Comment: @whirlwin I already have `SetProperties()` which sets properties such as `Name`, `Enabled` and such. It also calls my `SetSizeAndLocation` method, which also needs to get called elsewhere, without setting any other properties.

Comment: @Vadim The first concern is of course how I call my methods and what methods I have. I will only have one method and that's it. Now the second concern is; having one method is a must, what should this method be called then?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Better than mine! :) Gonna use it if there will be no better suggestions xd I'm from finland and can't really think of any english words, dictionary didn't help me either.

Comment: Do note that SetBounds() is probably more appropriate for `X1,Y1, X2,Y2` and less so for `X,Y,W,H` . I would probably choose `SetSizeAndLocation()` myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i often find that position+dimension of a window are referenced together as "geometry" of the window, e.g. in [tcl/tk windowmanagement](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/wm.htm#M26).

you also find this in the X-window system.

Comment: Ahh I would prefer `geometry` myself too, but I guess I'll use `bounds` since it seems to be default in windows :)

Comment: I decided to choose this one over `Bounds` after all, never liked microsoft's names ;P

Comment: Geometry was exactly the word I was trying to recall.   I think naming conventions are constructive.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows Forms, the [`Control.Bounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds.aspx) property allows you to get or set a [Rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx) that contains both the size and location of a control, so I think `SetBounds` would be a good name for your method.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know such a property existed! :) Gonna use this one since it's default in windows, and I am working with windows forms after all.

Answer (score 0):

Rectangle. Like the shape of a window. A rectangle object consists of both the location and size of a rectangular shape.

Comment: In what context does a rectangle specify it's location? (Just curious)

Comment: In canvases, for example, when you create a shape you specify somehow its coordinates.